# How to add the Oracle driver to Arquillian's managed Wildfly?

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss-arquillian

I am using Arquillian to test some parts of my code. In order to run specific tests using materialized views I cannot rely on H2, thus I have to change it to a real Oracle database.

For that I created a small Docker container running Oracle Database 11g XE, adding a user "db". Then I added a *oracle-ds.xml* which I also added to my Arquillian deployment. But it is not able to detect the oracle driver:

> Caused by: java.lang.Exception: {
>       "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.oracle"],
>       "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.data-source.\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.OracleTestDs\"
>   is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.oracle]"] }

On my local machine I added it manually, but it won't work in Arquillian's managed Wildfly - or at least I don't know how.

I tried to add it directly, but it also does not work:

```
PomEquippedResolveStage pomFile = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml");

WebArchive archive = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
    .addAsLibraries(pomFile.resolve("org.assertj:assertj-core").withTransitivity().asFile())
    .addAsLibraries(pomFile.resolve("com.oracle:ojdbc6").withTransitivity().asFile())
    // add many classes....
    .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
    .addAsResource("import.sql")
    .addAsResource("log4j2.xml")
    .addAsManifestResource("oracle-ds.xml")
    .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
```

This is just adds the oracle driver to the war file, but my code relies on the driver in the Wildfly container. Is there a way to deploy it to the Wildfly provided through Arquillian?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try replacing

`.addAsManifestResource("oracle-ds.xml")` with `.addAsWebInfResource("oracle-ds.xml", "oracle-ds.xml")`

but that doesn't seem to address your problem.

In one of my .pom files, I have the following plugin, that copies the oracle driver to the folder where it is needed (I believe both the `module.xml`and the `ojdbc6` is necessary). Perhaps you can infer from this to solve your problem.

```
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-antrun-plugin}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <echo message="copy file from ${basedir}/target/test-classes/${test.standalone.xml}" />
                <delete file="${basedir}/target/wildfly-${wildfly.version}/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml" />
                <copy file="${basedir}/target/test-classes/${test.standalone.xml}" toFile="${basedir}/target/wildfly-${wildfly.version}/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml" />
                <copy file="${basedir}/src/test/resources/module.xml" toFile="${basedir}/target/wildfly-${wildfly.version}/modules/system/layers/base/com/oracle/ojdbc6/main/module.xml" />
                <copy file="${basedir}/src/test/resources/ojdbc6.jar" toFile="${basedir}/target/wildfly-${wildfly.version}/modules/system/layers/base/com/oracle/ojdbc6/main/ojdbc6.jar" />
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: As you can see in the error message in my question, the datasource has been found and is used. But the driver is missing. So I need to find a way to add the oracle driver.